# RMS values above 0 dbFS?

Tags: audio

I wonder why several RMS meters I'm using for music production show RMS values above 0.

For example, when using an input signal with a constant DC of 1 (0 dbFS), I get these results, although [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#In_common_waveforms) that in such cases, the RMS is equal to the amplitude of the direct current.

### Samplitude Pro X (RMS: 2.9)

[image]

### TT Dynamic Range Meter (RMS 3.0)

[image]

Whereas other meters show the values I expect:

### Voxengo SPAN (RMS: 0.0)

[image]

Why is it that meters come to such different results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

0 dBFS refers to a full-scale sine wave or more rarely a full-scale square wave.

ITU-T telephony Recs. [P.381](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-P.381) and [P.382](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-P.382) and [reportedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS) the paywalled digital audio device measurement standards AES17-1998 and IEC 61606 define that full-scale sine wave is 0 dBFS. ITU-T Rec. P.10/G.100 (11/2017) does not make the distinction and defines dBfs (sic) as *"relative power level expressed in decibels, referred to the maximum possible digital level (full scale)"*.

Full scale DC has the same RMS value as a full-scale square wave, but is 3.010299956 dBFS RMS if the 0 dBFS reference is a full-scale sine wave. Looks like the different programs use a different reference (square or sine). Samplitude Pro X might use some approximation of RMS that gives in this case a 0.1 dB unit error.

The calculations:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(x)^2dx}{2\pi} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$10\log_{10}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx -3.010299956$$

Comment: All the standards I've read agree that FS sine is 0 dBFS, and that FS square is +3 dBFS, so it seems it's always an RMS measurement (never peak) and there's no ambiguity.  dBov is similar but 3 dB lower, so FS sine is -3 dBov and FS square is 0 dBov.

Comment: @endolith Adobe Audition 3 has *RMS Settings*: *0 dB = FS Sine Wave* or *0 dB = FS Square Wave*. They don't directly call the measure dBFS.

Comment: Yes, Audition was my first introduction to this concept